Does the order in which you list the join columns matter in pyspark
If I'm joining on 2 columns, say product_type and product_name, and product_type is higher up in the hierarchy (e.g 100 product_types each having 100 product_names), in terms of speed does it matter which column I list first?
example:
is this:
df1.join(df2, on =["product_type", "product_name"], how="left")
faster than this:
df1.join(df2, on =["product_name", "product_type"], how="left")
I've tried this:
df1.join(df2, on =["product_type", "product_name"], how="left")
and it worked, but I'm wondering if this:
df1.join(df2, on =["product_name", "product_type"], how="left")
is the same speed or slower

This should not matter for the performance. You could try it out by timing, but I wouldn't worry about it.
